# VBA function call from excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a function to concatenate all cells in a range in a single cell. Everything works ok with the function.

```
Function transposerange(Rg As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xStr As String
    For Each xCell In Rg
        If Not IsEmpty(xCell.Value) Then
            xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & " "
        End If
    Next
    transposerange = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
End Function
```

If I save it in the opened workbook, I can call it from excel. If I save this function to my personal workbook, it doesn't appear in excel when I want to call it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you saved your personal workbook as a macro enabled workbook?

Comment: File should be .xlsm or .xlsb to save VBA code

Comment: i don't think so, i see that it's called personal.xlsb. How do I change the file from .xlsb to .xlsm because I can't find it in %appdata%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use this function in your spreadsheets, type Personal.xlsb!transposerange(somerange). If you want just transposerange you must make add-id comprising this UDF.