# Finding out which function called other funciton in VBA excel

Tags: excel, function, debugging, method-call

Problem
I have an excel file with a quite complicated VBA code behind and I am having some problems to track back and debug the errors.
Sometimes a function B gets a value that it should not get and crashes, but at this point it is not possible for me to know which other funciton called that function B, and the anylys process to finding it out is very much time consuming.

My solution
The solution could be transform all the functions I have in the following way:

```
Sub foo1(variable1 as string)
    'do whatever
End Sub
```

into

```
Sub foo1(variable1 as string, inforvariable as string)
    'do whatever
End Sub
```

Infovariable being the name of the function calling.
This is obviously very time consuming (refactoring everything). Besides I dont know neither how to access the name of the "sub" of funcion of the code calling, something like:

```
infovariable = self.name
call foo1(variable1, inforvariable)
```

Does not seems to exists in VBA

Some ideas?

I have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845944/dynamic-function-calls-in-excel-vba), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134785/vba-function-call-from-excel), and here

Comment: Can you use `Debug.Assert` at the start of Function B to catch the invalid value, and then skip out the end of the Function to see where it was called from?  (e.g. `Debug.Assert Deliminator > 0` for a divide-by-zero error)

Comment: For a error handler that gives a message showing all the callers above the error see [vba error handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your macro, put a breakpoint on the line with the problem (in case the line gets called too often, add a condition only to break upon that condition), and view the call stack (keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+L`).

Comment: This works, but I am looking for a general solution. A way of changing my way of programming. A am not reffering to a particular function breaking, but in general how to program ANY funciton in a way that when it breaks (error) and I edit the VBA editor, I know "who" (which other funciton or sub) called the funciton given error.

Comment: A general solution seems not to exist, but maybe you might use following system: declare your subfunction as `subfunction(..., string parent)`, and every time you call it (in a parent function) you enter the name of that parent function. In C++ you might use `__FUNCTION` but this seems not to exist in VBA.

Comment: thanks Dominique, thats what I ended up doing. I have to say it is annoying because you might have to refactor a lot of already existing funciotns....